# AutoLisp 2021 Too few arguments error on (apply (lambda

Tags: lisp, autodesk, autolisp

We have installed the latest Autodesk 2021 and one of our scripts (a modified @Lee Mac) which strips and formats some input text now fails. This script runs perfectly on 2019 and below. I can't seem to work out why there is a difference.

I have substituted the original "vl-catch-all-apply" to "apply" so I could catch the error. The error is:

```
Too few arguments
```

This occurs as it hits the '(lambda function call. The code is below with the call:

```
(defun GDD:removeinfo (rgx str)
(if
    (null
        (vl-catch-all-error-p
            (setq str
                (apply
                   '(lambda nil
                        (vlax-put-property rgx 'global     actrue)
                        (vlax-put-property rgx 'multiline  actrue)
                        (vlax-put-property rgx 'ignorecase acfalse) 
                        (foreach pair
                           '(
                                ("\032"     . "\\\\\\\\")
                                ("\n"        . "\\\\P")
                                ("$1"       . "\\\\(\\\\[ACcFfHKkLlOopQTW])|\\\\[ACcFfHKkLlOopQTW][^\\\\;]*;|\\\\[ACcFfKkHLlOopQTW]")
                                ("$1$2/$3"  . "([^\\\\])\\\\S([^;]*)[/#\\^]([^;]*);")
                                ("$1$2"     . "\\\\(\\\\S)|[\\\\](})|}")
                                ("$1"       . "[\\\\]({)|{")
                                ("\\$1$2$3" . "(\\\\[ACcFfHKkLlOoPpQSTW])|({)|(})")
                                ("\\\\"     . "\032")
                                (""     . "(?:.*\\n)*Const\\s+.*\\n")
                                        (""     . "\\w\\w\\d?\\s+\\d+\\s\\d+-\\d+-\\d+")
                                        (""     . "^\\s+\\n")
                            )
                            (vlax-put-property rgx 'pattern (cdr pair))
                            (setq str (vlax-invoke rgx 'replace str (car pair)))
                        )
                    )
                )
            )
        )
    )
    str
)
)
```

The call to this function is below. I've checked the "input" and it is identical to the 2019 version that works and the str is populated properly using the vlisp (vscode) debugger. I've run the same code and input through both and only the 2021 version fails?

```
(setq input (GDD:removeinfo (vlax-get-or-create-object "VBScript.RegExp") input))
```

I'm not that familiar with LISP and I'm stuck. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `<FUN>` stands for:

```
'(lambda nil
  (vlax-put-property rgx 'global     actrue)
  (vlax-put-property rgx 'multiline  actrue)
  (vlax-put-property rgx 'ignorecase acfalse) 
  (foreach pair
   '(("\032"     . "\\\\\\\\")
     ("\n"        . "\\\\P")
     ("$1"       . "\\\\(\\\\[ACcFfHKkLlOopQTW])|\\\\[ACcFfHKkLlOopQTW][^\\\\;]*;|\\\\[ACcFfKkHLlOopQTW]")
     ("$1$2/$3"  . "([^\\\\])\\\\S([^;]*)[/#\\^]([^;]*);")
     ("$1$2"     . "\\\\(\\\\S)|[\\\\](})|}")
     ("$1"       . "[\\\\]({)|{")
     ("\\$1$2$3" . "(\\\\[ACcFfHKkLlOoPpQSTW])|({)|(})")
     ("\\\\"     . "\032")
     (""     . "(?:.*\\n)*Const\\s+.*\\n")
     (""     . "\\w\\w\\d?\\s+\\d+\\s\\d+-\\d+-\\d+")
     (""     . "^\\s+\\n"))
   (vlax-put-property rgx 'pattern (cdr pair))
   (setq str (vlax-invoke rgx 'replace str (car pair)))))
```

The code you posted, rewritten more compactly, looks as follows:

```
(defun GDD:removeinfo (rgx str)
  (if (null (vl-catch-all-error-p
             (setq str (apply <FUN>))))
      str))
```

In particular, the call to `APPLY` has only one argument:

```
(apply <FUN>)
```

[`APPLY`](http://docs.autodesk.com/ACD/2011/ENU/filesALR/WS1a9193826455f5ff1a32d8d10ebc6b7ccc-6aae.htm) in Autolisp is a function of 2 parameters: a function, and a list of arguments.

The intent is that:

```
(apply f '(0 1))
```

... is evaluated as-if you called `(f 0 1)`, but with possibility of building the list of arguments at runtime.

You only gave one argument to `apply` in your code, so you need to also pass a list of arguments.
In your case, that would be the empty list:

```
(apply <FUN> nil)
```

Comment: The code already has a "nil" list being passed to the function call. I've also tried passing () without success. In case I''m being stupid can you please post exactly what the code should look like using the original function? I'm still not sure why this function fails in 2021 and works in 2019 - it seems odd.

Comment: @RobMascaro I edited the answer to add more explanations. It looks to me that there is no NIL list passed to apply, so maybe there was a copy-paste error somewhere. Also, I cannot test the code, so this is based on reference manuals and knowledge of other Lisps: there might be problems with the code I don't see.

Comment: Excellent answer and it solved the issue many thanks. I might add, the original code works correctly on Autodesk 2019 so there must be some stricter checking in Autodesk 2021.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of changing `vl-catch-all-apply` to `apply` in order to see the error, simply output the error as part of the *else* branch of the `if` statement, for example:

```
(if
    (null
        (vl-catch-all-error-p
            (setq str
                (vl-catch-all-apply
                    ...
                )
            )
        )
    )
    str
    (prompt (strcat "\nError: " (vl-catch-all-error-message str))) ;; Output error and return nil
)
```

---

Aside, whilst this code is relatively trivial, I'm not sure whether I agree with you appropriating 95% of the code for my function and stripping off my heading and author prefix.

Comment: For brevity I did not include the headers for the function call in the post - it is in the original code. You will note that I specifically mentioned that it was your script in the original post. Apologies if that wasn't made clear.

Comment: Just to let you know that the if else didn't work. It appears to fall out of the if statement once an error is reached (Too few arguments to the apply) and doesn't hit the prompt else statement at all. I'm not sure why as what you proposed looked correct.

Comment: I would need to see your implementation of my suggestion to determine the cause of the error - note that the `lambda` function being evaluated by `vl-catch-all-apply` requires **no** arguments (as indicated by the `nil` arguments list) - the `nil` that you see in the code is **not** being supplied as an argument as you stated in your comment to coredump above.

Comment: I've added the actual implementation in an edit for you. Called via: (setq input (GDD:removeinfo (vlax-get-or-create-object "VBScript.RegExp") input))

Answer (score 0):

Whoever wrote that code seemed not to be aware of the [`progn`](https://documentation.help/AutoLISP-Functions/WS1a9193826455f5ff1a32d8d10ebc6b7ccc-697c.htm) operator.

So that is to say, if we want to evaluate multiple expressions `e1`, `e2`, ... for the sake of a side effect that they produce, we do not have to do this:

```
;; wrap expressions in a dummy lambda and apply empty arg list to it
(apply (lambda () e1 e2 ...) nil)
```

We can just write this:

```
(progn e1 e2 ...)
```

That still leaves us with a strange code smell which looks like this:

```
(setq str (progn .... (setq str value)))
```

The code is assigning the variable `str` twice with the same value. The deeply nested `(setq str value)` puts `value` into `str` and then yields that value as a result. It's the last expression of the `progn` (originall, of the `lambda`) and so that value is also returned.  Then the outer `setq` wastefully stores it in `str` again. We just need one or the other:

```
;; set str as the side effect of the last form in the
;; progn; also yield that value.
(progn e1 e2 ...(setq str value))

;; assign value yielded from progn to str, then also
;; yield that value.
(setq str (progn e1 e2 ... value))
```

Comment: notice the original used `vl-catch-all-apply`, not plain `apply`. the former "Passes a list of arguments to a specified function and traps any exceptions" ([ref](https://documentation.help/AutoLISP-Functions/WS1a9193826455f5ff1a32d8d10ebc6b7ccc-68e7.htm)) and returns an "error" object normally, as can be seen [above](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61958917/849891). it provides the functionality of `unwind-protect`.